# How to achieve navbar-static-bottom class?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar

There is `navbar-static-top` `navbar-fixed-top` and `navbar-fixed-bottom` but `navbar-static-bottom` just doesn't work in Bootstrap. Is there any way to achieve this effect?

Comment: Are you after a sticky footer bar?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: you want to stick the footer totally at the bottom which corresponds to the page height.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm after. I'm trying to create a div at the bottom for a 'contact me' section with images of social media icons, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="contents">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <!-- some contents -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <!-- some contents -->
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    background-color: #F3F3F3;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.contents {
    height: 1500px;
}

footer {
    background-color: rgb(34, 42, 53);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; /* absolutely bottom */
    width: 100%;
}

.clearfix {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: look at the footer, to verify if the footer sticks, change `.contents` height.